# Fishpig's Wordpress Integration in Magento Error

Tags: blogs, integration

I have installed the Fishpig's Wordpress Integration in magento, After the integration i got the 'There was an error logging you into WordPress. Please check your WordPress Admin credentials below and try again' error in magento admin end.

How might I troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 4):

In your Magento Admin page, you should see the Wordpress in your menu bar. Follow the navigation for Wordpress -> Settings -> WP-Auto-Login Details. There, you should be able to enter the username and password you use when signing into Wordpress admin.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, even though I knew the login and password were correct it showed same error message. I fixed it by navigating to the WP admin-login page, using forgot password and updating password from the email link.  I had to install PEAR and postfix on my server before the email reminder would send.

Answer (score 0):

Auto login problem in fishpig wordpress extension because there are not set REFERER Location in header (HTTP Request).

Add this code after 532 line

$curl->addOption(CURLOPT_REFERER, true);

in Fishpig_Wordpress_Helper_System

Comment: This code has been added to the newer versions of Fishpig, it is present in v.4.3.1.2