# Fishpig: Autologin not working authentication exception because of index.php

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, magento, magento-1.7, fishpig

I have Fishpig Wordpress Integration installed along with Magento CE 1.702.

Wordpress is set up like this :

```
Database
    Charset                              utf8
    Table Prefix                         wp_
integration
    Integrate Theme                      Yes
    Home URL                             blog
    Path                                 wp
    Single Store                         no
```

I removed index.php from the frontend using this rewrite rule :

```
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>`
```

The problem is the Fishpig Wordpress autologin has stopped working with the error:

> Unable to login. Check your WordPress Admin login details below.

Stacktrace :

```
> 2014-05-08T13:25:36+00:00 DEBUG (7): exception 'Exception' with message 'WordPress Auto Login Failed: HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required
Date: Thu, 08 May 2014 13:25:36 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 482
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' in /nfs/c03/h03/mnt/168517/domains/dummyurl.com/html/app/code/community/Fishpig/Wordpress/Helper/System.php:493
Stack trace:
#0 /nfs/c03/h03/mnt/168517/domains/dummyurl.com/html/app/code/community/Fishpig/Wordpress/controllers/Adminhtml/WordpressController.php(34): Fishpig_Wordpress_Helper_System->loginToWordPress('myUserName', 'myPassword', 'http://dummyurl...')
#1 /nfs/c03/h03/mnt/168517/domains/dummyurl.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Fishpig_Wordpress_Adminhtml_WordpressController->loginAction()
#2 /nfs/c03/h03/mnt/168517/domains/dummyurl.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('login')
#3 /nfs/c03/h03/mnt/168517/domains/dummyurl.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#4 /nfs/c03/h03/mnt/168517/domains/dummyurl.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#5 /nfs/c03/h03/mnt/168517/domains/dummyurl.com/html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#6 /nfs/c03/h03/mnt/168517/domains/dummyurl.com/html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#7 {main}
```

I contacted Fishpig support and they said :

> You need to configure your Magento installation not to use index.php.

I removed index.php from the admin area like this :

```
    RewriteRule ^index.php/admin/(.*)$ /my-admin/$1 [L,R]
```

This didn't fix the autologin problem and I noticed that the autologin button url contained the index.php so I removed index.php in the wordpress .htaccess like this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/wp/index.php/(.*)$ /wp/$1 [L,R]
</IfModule>
```

This removed the index.php from the admin url but not in the autologin button

http://dummyurl.com/index.php/admin/wordpress/login/key/72a947f0e9452bfd6e92258d31ce7cd2/

I have been searching and wrecking my head with this, any help is appreciated.

Comment: As Ben stated in his answer I didn't need to change the default Wordpress .htaccess file.  I only changed this file after the login problem started happening.    I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857652/fishpigs-wordpress-integration-in-magento-error) answer which got it working by adding a referrer to the header(http request) - `Auto login problem in fishpig wordpress extension because there are not set REFERER Location in header (HTTP Request).

Add this code after 532 line

$curl->addOption(CURLOPT_REFERER, true);

in Fishpig_Wordpress_Helper_System`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the auto-login functionality working, you only require the default content in your .htaccess file and do not need to add any custom code in here. The following is all you need:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /wp/
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

It would help if you included the actual URL to your Magento site, as this would very quickly answer a few questions.

Comment: Thanks Ben for the reply, your suggestion was correct regarding the wordpress .htaccess file, but the autologin issue started happening before I changed that file. This code fixed the autologin problem - `Add this code after 532 line  $curl->addOption(CURLOPT_REFERER, true);  in Fishpig_Wordpress_Helper_System`

Comment: Thank you for the code. I will test it and look at adding it into the next release. If you can mark this answer as accepted for future users :)