# FishPig Magento Extension : WordPress Auto Login Failed and not even login manually

Tags: php, wordpress, magento, blogs, fishpig

Error:

> WordPress Auto Login Failed: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found Date: Thu, 12 May 2016 07:09:31 GMT Server: Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12 X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.12 Set-Cookie: frontend=7pr2r9qub10h5skdbqot9dbiu7; expires=Thu, 12-May-2016 08:09:32 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/magento; domain=127.0.0.1; HttpOnly Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0 Pragma: no-cache X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN Status: 404 File not found Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

I have read lots of blog related this issue and I have tried all solution but it didn't work for me.

I have tried to add "Add this code after 532 line `$curl->addOption(CURLOPT_REFERER, true);` in Fishpig_Wordpress_Helper_System" but inside system.php line no 532 is not present.

[Fishpig: Autologin not working authentication exception because of index.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23544418/fishpig-autologin-not-working-authentication-exception-because-of-index-php)

Can anybody have any other option to resolve this error.

I am using `Magento version 1.9.2.4` and `wordpress version 4.5`

Comment: Thanks @severinolorillajr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the question, it appears that both the auto login system and a manual login aren't working. If I read this correctly then that's your issue.

The auto login system essentially performs a manual login for you by submitting an identical HTTP post request to wp-login.php. This means that if you can't login manually, the auto login won't be able to either.

To resolve this issue, determine why you can't login manually. If you can see the login page and can't login, you either have incorrect details or there is a cookie issue.

If you see the login page but the CSS is missing, you probably have a URL set incorrectly in WordPress.

If when going to the login page you get redirected to a different URL, your 'siteurl' option is incorrect and needs to be changed in the wp_options table.

If you post a link to your site, I will be able to tell you more.

Comment: I was installed module on my local server so I am not able to share my website url with you. Also, when i installed wordpress it was working fine. Error occurred when I changed my wordpress **SiteUrl** and **Home Url** as per the module instruction , I am unable to login manually [http://127.0.0.1/magento/blog/wp-admin/] url says page isn't redirect properly.

Comment: If you can't login manually, you cannot auto login. Fix the manual login and then you can login automatically. If the page is redirecting, you have set your WordPress 'siteurl' incorrectly. This should be the WordPress installation URL.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed *SiteUrl* and *Home Url* as previous one. then I tried to login manually and it will work perfectly. Magento auto login is also work perfectly.